# How to change the acquired Raw Image Size in C# when using the EDSDK?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, enums, sdk

I want to acquire MRaw or SRaw.
As an example: The Canon EOS 5D has these raw sizes:

```
(6) RAW: Approx. 22.10 Megapixels (5760 x 3840) 
(7) M-RAW: Approx. 10.50 Megapixels (3960 x 2640) 
(8) S-RAW: Approx. 5.50 Megapixels (2880 x 1920)
```

These could be set on the physical camera.  But I want to set these in software.  The software I have sets ISO and Shutter speed, but I'm not seeing how to add the raw Image size (maybe quality?) as a setting.  Or I'm missing it.  I'm looking through what little documentation the EDSDK provides.

There seems to be this item: "EDSDK.PropID_ImageQuality" that allows the idea of changing from Large to Medium, and so forth.  But my code does not have a handle for 'ImageQuality'.

It seems the latest version of the  EDSDK has added an ImageQuality Enum which includes:

```
    EdsImageQuality_LR = 0x0064ff0f,    /* RAW */
    EdsImageQuality_MR = 0x0164ff0f,    /* MRAW(SRAW1) */
    EdsImageQuality_SR = 0x0264ff0f,    /* SRAW(SRAW2) */
```

...This is just a sample of a much larger enum... But I haven't figured out how to make use of those different value properties.  They were not there in the original SDK.

Note: Canons EOS Utility has no problem shooting in the different formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
uint setError = EDSDK.EdsSetPropertyData(camera, EDSDK.PropID_ImageQuality, 0, sizeof(UInt32), EDSDK.ImageQuality.EdsImageQuality_MR);
```

I needed to set this property data.  I could not find this anywhere on the web.  I just stumbled at it, and it did it.  All EdsSetPropertyData commands return an error code if they don't work.  I just followed the format of a couple of other ones in the code.

Presumably I could set it to other formats as well, not just EdsImageQuality_MR.  But this answers my question...

Comment: Also make sure you are using the latest EDSDK.